# Why was this "duplicate" flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190464/having-issue-with-css-in-login-page) on the styling of "autofilled" inputs as being a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css), which has a very good answer to the problem.

However, my flag was disputed and I'd just like to enquire why that was in order to help me to raise more helpful flags in the future.

Comment: Perhaps the edit marked it disputed?

Comment: I checked after I made the edit and the flag was still pending.

Comment: All we know is that three people felt that it wasn't worth closing. Why, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

They are not duplicates.

The former have a positioning or z-index problem while the latter have a problem with auto-completion filling the wrong form and css coloring the wrong fields.

I'd agree both might be *triggered* by an auto-completion script, but apart from that, they're not quite duplicates.